# how to fix the OpenGL shading language warning

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

When I write GL Shading Language using .vsh or .fsh as file extension. I always got the warning like this:

```
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/luo/Desktop/粒子系统/OpenGL_ParticleSystems
/OpenGL_ParticleSystems/Emitter.vsh' of type sourcecode.glsl for architecture i386

 warning: no rule to process file '/Users/luo/Desktop/粒子系统/OpenGL_ParticleSystems
 /OpenGL_ParticleSystems/Emitter.fsh' of type sourcecode.glsl for architecture i386
```

Anyone who can tell me how to fix this warning, or maybe I have to use .glsl as the file extension.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

luo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this  warning and make the program work well. there have two ways to achieve it:

1. click the blue project icon --> Build Phase --> Compile Sources --> add *.vsh and *.fsh to it using "+"
2. click the blue project icon -->Build Phase --> copy Bundle Resources --> add *.vsh and *.fsh to it using "+"

I hope it is useful to the people who run into the same problem.